# Performing a heroku db:push gives ArgumentError: invalid date (Sequel::InvalidValue) is this something standard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, push

Performing a heroku db:push

everything seem to be going ok

Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:05
Sending indexes
schema_migrat: 100% |=====================================| Time: 00:00:00
users:         100% |==========================================================| Time: 00:00:01
histories:     100% |========================================================| Time: 00:00:00
Sending data
4 tables, 587 records

schema_migrat: 100% |==============================================| Time: 00:00:00

when i get

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1573:in `new_by_frags': ArgumentError: invalid date (Sequel::InvalidValue)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1618:in`parse'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:222:in `string_to_datetime'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/timezones.rb:92:in`convert_input_timestamp'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/timezones.rb:163:in `convert_timestamp'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/timezones.rb:46:in`database_to_application_timestamp'

**EDIT: Adding Schema/Migration**

```
t.string "apothiki" 
t.string "timh" 
t.datetime "created_at" 
t.datetime "updated_at" 
t.string "photo_file_name" 
t.string "photo_content_type" 
t.integer "photo_file_size" 
t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
```

Comment: please post your migration/schema. Heroku uses PostgreSQL so there is probably a difference between the date types.

Comment: t.string   "apothiki"
    t.string   "timh"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"

Comment: that's your entire schema? nothing looks weird.

Comment: Did you do a heroku db:migrate first?

Comment: did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634693/problem-pushing-sqlite3-db-to-heroku-lib-taps-schema-rb30in-sqlite-config

Comment: thanks however i dont understand i must generate a different schema.rb than the one i have now ?

Comment: what database vendor are you currently using (SQLite, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: SQlite , i also installed the pg gem thought it might help but still the same problem

Comment: Ok, i was importing my data from an CSV file but all my datetimes from created and modified were empty, and that wasnt a problem with sqlite deploying locally. once i filled proper dates to all the records it sure pushed the db okay. so solved! thanks for the help!

Comment: cool. you should answer your own question in case others come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i was importing my data from an CSV file but all my datetimes from created and modified were empty, and that wasnt a problem with sqlite deploying locally. once i filled proper dates to all the records it sure pushed the db okay. so solved! thanks for the help!